# Issue with pthreads_cond_wait and queue'ing pthreads

Tags: c++, windows, pthreads

I'm trying to have pthreads run multiple instances of a function at once, to increase runtime speed and efficiency. My code is supposed to spawn threads and keep them open for whenever there is more items in the queue. Then those threads are supposed to do 'something'. The code is supposed to ask to "continue?" when there are no more items in the queue, and if I type "yes", then items should be added to the queue and the threads should continue doing 'something'. This is what I have so far,

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>
# include <pthread.h>
# include <queue>

using namespace std;
# define NUM_THREADS 100

int main ( );
queue<int> testQueue;
void *checkEmpty(void* arg);
void *playQueue(void* arg);
void matrix_exponential_test01 ( );
void matrix_exponential_test02 ( );
pthread_mutex_t queueLock;
pthread_cond_t queue_cv;

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS+1];
    pthread_mutex_init(&queueLock, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init (&queue_cv, NULL);

    for( int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ )
    {
       pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, playQueue, (void*)NULL);
    }

    string cont = "yes";
    do
    {
        cout<<"Continue? ";
        getline(cin, cont);
        pthread_mutex_lock (&queueLock);
        for(int z=0; z<10; z++)
        {

           testQueue.push(1);

        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&queueLock);
    }while(cont.compare("yes"));

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&queueLock);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&queue_cv);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}

void* checkEmpty(void* arg)
{
    while(true)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock (&queueLock);
        if(!testQueue.empty()){
            pthread_cond_signal(&queue_cv);}
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&queueLock);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* playQueue(void* arg)
{
    while(true)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&queue_cv, &queueLock);
        pthread_mutex_lock (&queueLock);
        if(!testQueue.empty())
        {
            testQueue.pop();
            cout<<testQueue.size()<<endl;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&queueLock);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

So my issue lies with the fact that the code goes into deadlock, and I cant figure out where the issue occurs. I'm no veteran with multithreading so its very easy for me to make a mistake here. I am also running this on Windows.

Comment: When `pthread_cond_wait` returns, the lock has been acquired. So you shouldn't be re-locking it immediately after with `pthread_mutex_lock`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues :

- The condition variable `queue_cv` is never signaled. You can signal it with `pthread_cond_signal` after having pushed elements in the queue : `pthread_cond_signal(&queue_cv);`
- In `playQueue`, you try to acquire the lock after returning from `pthread_cond_wait` : since your mutex is not reentrant, this is undefined behavior (this is likely the source of your deadlock). Just remove the `pthread_mutex_lock (&queueLock);`

**Note:**

I'm not sure what is it's true purpose, but the `checkEmpty()` method is never called

Comment: I actually have a question, I ran test with 1000 trials, and it ended up that the unthreaded version ran faster. I feel as though this shouldnt be the case since the task is to process math. I've made the changes that have been suggested, changed the while loop into a for 1:1000 loop, and added a `while(!testQueue.empty()){pthread_cond_signal;}`. Why does the unthreaded version work faster than the threaded version? There are also a lot of print statements in the function.